# Why does it not print 4 patterns?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[] Array1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};     
int pattern =0;
int first = 1;
for(int i=0; i<10;i+=2)
{
    if(Array1[i] + Array1[first] > 7) 
    {
        pattern ++;
    }
    first+=2;
}
System.out.println("The total number of patterns: " + pattern);
```

What I am trying to do: Plus the adjacent numbers and check whether it is more than 7. If it is print 1 pattern and so forth

Why does it not print 4 patterns?

Comment: This should print 3. Only 5+6, 7+8, and 9+10 are > 7. You would get 4 if you compared using `>=`.

Comment: You mentioned adjacent, so is 2+3, 4+5, 6+7, 8+9, etc not adjacent? Just want to confirm what you are expecting is what you have written.

Answer (score 0):

An array starts with a 0 Index, therefore your pattern does the following:

1 + 2 = 3 (Less than 7)

`(Array1[0] + Array1[1])`

3 + 4 = 7 (Less than 7, `>=` would represent Less than Or Equal To 7)

`(Array1[2] + Array1[3])`

5 + 6 = 11 (Greater than 7)

7 + 8 = 15 (Greater than 7)

9 + 10 = 19 (Greater than 7)

As you can see, only 3 of the results are greater than 7

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after your for loop starts.

> `System.out.println(Array1[i] + "+" + Array1[first] + "=" + (Array1[i] + Array1[first]));`

It will explain what is happening with your code. The output would be ::

> 1+2=3
>
> 3+4=7
>
> 5+6=11
>
> 7+8=15
>
> 9+10=19
>
> The total number of patterns: 3

As you can see only three times the pattern is greater than 7. Therefore your output.

If you use eclipse you can add breakpoints and understand the flow of your code. Here is a link to a tutorial for [debugging in eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)